# weird result after filtering with Gaussian Recursive Filter

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, gaussian

I implemented Gaussian recursive filter(by R. Deriche) using OpenCV and c++. However, the result I'm getting is weird. I also tried normalizing the resulting image between 0 and 255 but even that doesn't help.

any help would be great
[image: input and output images]

Comment: Comments for negative vote would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a sample of code; we have no idea what you're doing wrong if we have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: thanks, ill be editing the main post with chunks of what ive done.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur did you compare the gaussian you obtained with your implementation against the standard simple way to obtain gaussians ? If they are much different, then your implementation of the method is wrong. If they are nearly equal, then how you are convolving is wrong.

Comment: Better yet, explain the algorithm step-by-step, with intermediate results and code. E.g. this are the filter parameters I get, this is the 1d impulse response, this is the 2d impulse response, etc. Unless the error in your code is totally obvious, that's what anyone trying to help you would have to do, too.

Comment: It is too much trouble explaining in details gaussian recursive filter by Deriche, not a good fit for a single question.

Comment: I have added code. I tried again but no good results....thanks in advance

Comment: I cant find the error in your code, but when I have gotten images like the one in your question, it has been because I ran over the range of the variables that I was using.  You cannot cast a float to an unsigned char without handling the under / overflow.  For example your line  output.at<uchar>(i,j) = (unsigned char)((float)fabs(sumvec[j]) + 0.5f) assumes that sumvec[j] + .5 is within 0 to 255.

Comment: the sum of the two vectors will cause the range to exceed 255. how can I handle the under/overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Image has to be taken as float in the input. The processing has to be done on this float image and then normalize the result using

```
normalize(output, output,0,255,NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);
```

Thanks for helping guys.